# how can I output a string with '\n' by echo in bash

Tags: bash, shell

Here is my problem : I want to output the name of process and here is my sentence:
`ps -a | tr -s ' ' ' ' | cut -d' ' -f5 | sed '1d'`,and it works as my exceptation.
Here is the result:

```
sh-4.3# ps -a | tr -s ' ' ' ' | cut -d' ' -f5 | sed '1d'                                        
ps                                                                                              
tr                                                                                              
cut                                                                                             
sed
```

But if I use " echo `ps -a | tr -s ' ' ' ' | cut -d' ' -f5 | sed '1d'` ",the result isn't the same with the result I get by using the previous sentence.
The result like this:

```
sh-4.3# echo `ps -a | tr -s ' ' ' ' | cut -d' ' -f5 | sed '1d'`                                 
sh ps tr cut sed
```

I want to get a first result by using a sentence in a **Shell Script**,how should I do?

Comment: Use `$()` instead of backticks and quote it. `echo "$(ps -a | tr -s ' ' ' ' | cut -d' ' -f5 | sed '1d')" `. Or you could just run the command normally and it would give the same result...

Comment: `echo "$(ps -a -o comm=)"` will work, but the `echo` is totally redundant.  Is this merely an academic question?

Comment: I use `echo` because I want to print the outputs when I am running a *.sh file ,and I have not any idea but  using `echo` @WilliamPursell

Comment: Yes, but the echo is redundant.  The `ps` command writes to the same place that echo does, so you might as well just let `ps` run.

Comment: @Sineatos, ...to state what @WilliamPursell is telling you a bit differently, `ps -a -o comm=` will also print its output, with no echo at all.

Answer (score 1):

Use quotes.

```
echo "$(ps -a | tr -s ' ' ' ' | cut -d' ' -f5 | sed '1d')"
```

Comment: ...but why do this, instead of just running `ps -a | tr -s ' ' ' ' | cut -d' ' -f5 | sed '1d'` alone, and not capturing the output at all?

Answer (score 0):

For your particular case, quoting will work:

```
echo "`ps -a | tr -s ' ' ' ' | cut -d' ' -f5 | sed '1d'`"
```

or:

```
echo "$(ps -a | tr -s ' ' ' ' | cut -d' ' -f5 | sed '1d')"
```

And if you want to interpret `\n` in any string, then here's an example:

```
echo -e "\nString\nWith\nNewline"
#quoting is necessary
```

You have to make use of the `-e` option.

Comment: What's the meaning of `$()` in the sentence ` " $(`ps -a | tr -s ' ' ' ' | cut -d' ' -f5 | sed '1d') " `? Is the same with `$VariableName` ? @Jahid

Comment: @Sineatos no, It's same as using backticks, ```, But it has some advantanges over backtick: it can easily be nested, and it improves readability of code.